# CreateFile fails when calling from message queue after first call

Tags: .net, vb.net, winapi, createfile, writefile

I have a winforms project in VB.Net 2017.  I have a routine called LogDataFiles which is using CreateFile and WriteFile API's to write a small data file to disk.  When running from source, I can successfully write the files by either calling the LogDataFiles routine directly via command button, or by posting a message to a message queue, which in turn calls the LogDataFiles function.

However, once compiled and running from an executable, the behavior changes.  I can still write the files by calling the routine directly via command button, but CreateFile fails with error code 998 if I post message to message queue, then call the LogDataFiles function.  The function tries to write 5 files.  On the first try, the first file will be written, but all other files fail on CreateFile with error 998.  Subsequent tries via message queue all fail, even on first file.

I need help figuring out why the logic fails in executable mode, when it works running from source.

This is the relevant code.  First the API declarations, then the logging routines, followed by the queue logic.

```
  Private Structure SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES
    Dim nLength As Integer
    Dim lpSecurityDescriptor As Integer
    Dim bInheritHandle As Boolean
  End Structure

  Private Declare Auto Function CreateFile Lib "kernel32.dll" (ByVal lpFileName As String,
   ByVal dwDesiredAccess As Int32, ByVal dwShareMode As Int32, ByRef lpSecurityAttributes As SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES,
  ByVal dwCreationDisposition As Int32, ByVal dwFlagsAndAttributes As Int32, ByVal hTemplateFile As IntPtr) As Integer

  Private Declare Auto Function CreateFile Lib "kernel32.dll" (ByVal lpFileName As String,
   ByVal dwDesiredAccess As Int32, ByVal dwShareMode As Int32, ByRef lpSecurityAttributes As IntPtr,
  ByVal dwCreationDisposition As Int32, ByVal dwFlagsAndAttributes As Int32, ByVal hTemplateFile As IntPtr) As Integer



  Private Declare Auto Function SetFilePointer Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hFile As Integer, _
      ByVal lDistanceToMove As Integer, ByRef lpDistanceToMoveHigh As Integer, _
      ByVal dwMoveMethod As Integer) As Long

  Private Declare Auto Function ReadFile Lib "Kernel32.dll" ( _
    ByVal hndRef As Integer, ByVal lpBuffer As Byte(), _
    ByVal numberOfBytesToRead As Integer, ByRef numberOfBytesRead As Integer, ByVal flag As Integer) As Boolean

  Private Declare Auto Function CloseHandle Lib "kernel32.dll" (ByVal hObject As Integer) As Boolean



  Private Declare Function GetDiskFreeSpaceEx Lib "kernel32" Alias "GetDiskFreeSpaceExA" (ByVal lpRootPathName As String, ByRef lpFreeBytesAvailableToCaller As Long, ByRef lpTotalNumberOfBytes As Long, ByRef lpTotalNumberOfFreeBytes As Long) As Long

  Private Declare Auto Function GetLastError Lib "kernel32" () As Long

  Private Declare Function WriteFile Lib "kernel32" (
        ByVal hTemplateFile As Integer, lpBuffer() As Byte,
        ByVal nNumberOfBytesToWrite As Int32,
       ByRef lpNumberOfBytesWritten As Int32, ByVal lpOverlapped As Int32) As Integer



  Private Declare Function GetDiskFreeSpace Lib "kernel32" Alias "GetDiskFreeSpaceA" _
 (ByVal lpRootPathName As String, ByRef lpSectorsPerCluster As UInt32, ByRef lpBytesPerSector As UInt32, ByRef lpNumberOfFreeClusters As UInt32, ByRef lpTtoalNumberOfClusters As UInt32) As Integer



  Private Declare Function FlushFileBuffers Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hFile As Integer) As Integer
  Private Declare Function GetTickCount Lib "kernel32" Alias "GetTickCount" () As Integer

  Private Const GENERIC_WRITE As Long = &H40000000
  Private Const GENERIC_READ As Long = &H80000000
  Private Const FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL As Long = &H80
  Private Const CREATE_ALWAYS As Long = 2
  Private Const OPEN_EXISTING As Long = 3
  Private Const OPEN_ALWAYS As Long = 4
  Private Const INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE As Long = -1

  ' CreateFile dwShareMode 
  Private Const FILE_SHARE_READ As Integer = &H1
  Private Const FILE_SHARE_WRITE As Integer = &H2

  ' Windows file cache related attributes
  Private Const WRITE_THROUGH As Long = &H80000000
  Private Const NO_BUFFERING As Long = &H20000000

  Friend Structure STORAGE_DEVICE_NUMBER
    Friend DeviceType As Integer
    Friend DeviceNumber As Integer
    Friend PartitionNumber As Integer
  End Structure

  Private Enum EFileAccess As System.Int32
    ''
    ''  The following are masks for the predefined standard access types
    ''

    DELETE = &H10000
    READ_CONTROL = &H20000
    WRITE_DAC = &H40000
    WRITE_OWNER = &H80000
    SYNCHRONIZE = &H100000

    STANDARD_RIGHTS_REQUIRED = &HF0000
    STANDARD_RIGHTS_READ = READ_CONTROL
    STANDARD_RIGHTS_WRITE = READ_CONTROL
    STANDARD_RIGHTS_EXECUTE = READ_CONTROL
    STANDARD_RIGHTS_ALL = &H1F0000
    SPECIFIC_RIGHTS_ALL = &HFFFF

    ''
    '' AccessSystemAcl access type
    ''

    ACCESS_SYSTEM_SECURITY = &H1000000

    ''
    '' MaximumAllowed access type
    ''

    MAXIMUM_ALLOWED = &H2000000

    ''
    ''  These are the generic rights.
    ''

    GENERIC_READ = &H80000000
    GENERIC_WRITE = &H40000000
    GENERIC_EXECUTE = &H20000000
    GENERIC_ALL = &H10000000
  End Enum

  Private Enum EFileShare
    FILE_SHARE_NONE = &H0
    FILE_SHARE_READ = &H1
    FILE_SHARE_WRITE = &H2
    FILE_SHARE_DELETE = &H4
  End Enum

  Private Enum ECreationDisposition
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Creates a new file, only if it does not already exist.
    ''' If the specified file exists, the function fails and the last-error code is set to ERROR_FILE_EXISTS (80).
    ''' If the specified file does not exist and is a valid path to a writable location, a new file is created.
    ''' </summary>
    CREATE_NEW = 1

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Creates a new file, always.
    ''' If the specified file exists and is writable, the function overwrites the file, the function succeeds, and last-error code is set to ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS (183).
    ''' If the specified file does not exist and is a valid path, a new file is created, the function succeeds, and the last-error code is set to zero.
    ''' For more information, see the Remarks section of this topic.
    ''' </summary>
    CREATE_ALWAYS = 2

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Opens a file or device, only if it exists.
    ''' If the specified file or device does not exist, the function fails and the last-error code is set to ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND (2).
    ''' For more information about devices, see the Remarks section.
    ''' </summary>
    OPEN_EXISTING = 3

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Opens a file, always.
    ''' If the specified file exists, the function succeeds and the last-error code is set to ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS (183).
    ''' If the specified file does not exist and is a valid path to a writable location, the function creates a file and the last-error code is set to zero.
    ''' </summary>
    OPEN_ALWAYS = 4

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Opens a file and truncates it so that its size is zero bytes, only if it exists.
    ''' If the specified file does not exist, the function fails and the last-error code is set to ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND (2).
    ''' The calling process must open the file with the GENERIC_WRITE bit set as part of the dwDesiredAccess parameter.
    ''' </summary>
    TRUNCATE_EXISTING = 5
  End Enum

  Private Enum EFileAttributes
    FILE_ATTRIBUTE_READONLY = &H1
    FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN = &H2
    FILE_ATTRIBUTE_SYSTEM = &H4
    FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY = &H10
    FILE_ATTRIBUTE_ARCHIVE = &H20
    FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DEVICE = &H40
    FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL = &H80
    FILE_ATTRIBUTE_TEMPORARY = &H100
    FILE_ATTRIBUTE_SPARSE_FILE = &H200
    FILE_ATTRIBUTE_REPARSE_POINT = &H400
    FILE_ATTRIBUTE_COMPRESSED = &H800
    FILE_ATTRIBUTE_OFFLINE = &H1000
    FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NOT_CONTENT_INDEXED = &H2000
    FILE_ATTRIBUTE_ENCRYPTED = &H4000
    FILE_ATTRIBUTE_VIRTUAL = &H10000

    'This parameter can also contain combinations of flags (FILE_FLAG_*) 
    FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS = &H2000000
    FILE_FLAG_DELETE_ON_CLOSE = &H4000000
    FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING = &H20000000
    FILE_FLAG_OPEN_NO_RECALL = &H100000
    FILE_FLAG_OPEN_REPARSE_POINT = &H200000
    FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED = &H40000000
    FILE_FLAG_POSIX_SEMANTICS = &H1000000
    FILE_FLAG_RANDOM_ACCESS = &H10000000
    FILE_FLAG_SEQUENTIAL_SCAN = &H8000000
    FILE_FLAG_WRITE_THROUGH = &H80000000
  End 

Enum


 Sub LogDataFiles()
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To 5
      Call WriteFileData(i)
    Next
  End Sub
  Sub WriteFileData(ByVal indexNo As Integer)


    Dim strFileName As String
    Dim bf As New BinaryFormatter
    Dim tmpStream As New MemoryStream
    Dim bytArray() As Byte

    'data inside defaults to all FF's
    Dim tmpStorage As New clsDataStorage
    Dim blnResult As Boolean
    Dim strTemp As String


    Try


      strFileName = dataPath & "File_" & indexNo.ToString & ".dat"

      'In real app, tmpStorage would be a more complex class so data is serialized
      'to allow it to be put into byte array
      'Must serialize the data first
      bf.Serialize(tmpStream, tmpStorage)
      bytArray = tmpStream.ToArray
      tmpStream.Close()

      Call testIO.Write_Serialized_Data_To_File(bytArray, strFileName)

      blnResult = testIO.Check_File_Contents_By_CRC(strFileName)
      If blnResult = True Then
        strTemp = strFileName & vbTab & vbTab & "CRC Okay"
      Else
        strTemp = strFileName & vbTab & vbTab & "** CRC ERROR **"
      End If
      Call AddToList(strTemp)


      'error handling
    Catch ex As Exception
      Call LogError(ex)

    Finally
      tmpStream = Nothing
      bf = Nothing
      bytArray = Nothing
      tmpStorage = Nothing



    End Try
  End 

Sub









  Sub Write_Serialized_Data_To_File(ByVal bytSerializedData() As Byte, ByVal strFileName As String)


    Dim lHandle As Integer

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim iBytesWritten As Integer
    Dim iResult As Integer
    Dim bytArray() As Byte
    Dim bytCRC() As Byte
    Dim intUBound As Integer
    Dim arrLogged() As Byte
    Dim bytTemp As Byte
    Dim blnExistsAlready As Boolean = False

    Dim intLoopCounter As Integer = 0
    Dim lngError As Long

    Dim lpSA As SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES


    Try

      intUBound = bytSerializedData.GetUpperBound(0)

      ReDim bytArray(intUBound)
      For i = 0 To intUBound
        bytTemp = bytSerializedData(i)
        bytArray(i) = bytTemp
      Next



      'check to see if file exists first
      Dim strFileExists As String = " "
      strFileExists = Dir(strFileName)
      strFileExists = Trim$(strFileExists)
      If Len(strFileExists) = 0 Then
        'file does not exist
        blnExistsAlready = False


      ElseIf (Len(strFileExists) > 0) Then
        blnExistsAlready = True
      End If

      ''open the file

      lpSA.nLength = Len(lpSA)


      If blnExistsAlready = True Then
        'open but do not create file
        lHandle = CreateFile(strFileName, GENERIC_WRITE, 0,
             lpSA, OPEN_EXISTING, NO_BUFFERING, IntPtr.Zero)

        Debug.WriteLine("Write handle exists is = " & lHandle.ToString)


      ElseIf blnExistsAlready = False Then
        'create new file
        lHandle = CreateFile(strFileName, GENERIC_WRITE, 0,
           lpSA, CREATE_ALWAYS, NO_BUFFERING, IntPtr.Zero)

        Debug.WriteLine("Write handle create is = " & lHandle.ToString)

      End If


      Debug.WriteLine("Write handle create is = " & lHandle.ToString)


      lngError = GetLastError()
      If lngError > 0 Then
        Debug.WriteLine("B after write last error is " & lngError.ToString)
        MsgBox("CreateFile Failure for " & strFileName & " -Error Code: " & lngError.ToString)

      Else

        'add CRC bytes to bytArray before logging to disk
        intUBound = bytArray.GetUpperBound(0)
        'get crc bytes
        bytCRC = CRC_CalcCRC(bytArray)
        'add crc bytes to array
        ReDim Preserve bytArray(intUBound + 2)  'for 2 crc bytes 
      bytArray(intUBound + 1) = bytCRC(1)
      bytArray(intUBound + 2) = bytCRC(0)

      ReDim arrLogged(intUBound + 2 + 4)
      For i = (intUBound + 2 + 4) To 4 Step -1
        arrLogged(i) = bytArray(i - 4)
      Next i
      'add upper bound of data array including CRC bytes to front of log before passing
      arrLogged = Convert_Long_To_Binary_Array_LSB_First((intUBound + 2), 0, 4, arrLogged)

      iResult = CInt(WriteFile(lHandle, arrLogged, Convert.ToInt32(Math.Ceiling(arrLogged.Length / SRAM_Drive_SectorSize) * SRAM_Drive_SectorSize), iBytesWritten, 0))

        'Call CloseHandle(lHandle)
      End If


      'error handling
    Catch ex As Exception
      Call LogError(ex)

    Finally
      If lHandle <> INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE Then
        Call CloseHandle(lHandle)
        'MsgBox("close handle  " & lHandle.ToString)
      End If

    End Try

  End Sub
```

Following is the queue related logic:

```
  Private Sub RxQueue_ReceiveCompleted(sender As Object, e As ReceiveCompletedEventArgs) Handles RxQueue.ReceiveCompleted
    Try

      Dim qMessage As Message = RxQueue.EndReceive(e.AsyncResult)
      Dim qBody As structEvent

      qBody = CType(qMessage.Body, structEvent)

      Call UpdateUI(qBody)

      RxQueue.BeginReceive()

      Return
    Catch ex As Exception
      Call LogError(ex)
    End Try

  End Sub
  Public Sub Load_RxQueue()


    Try

      With RxQueue
        .Path = nameOfQueue
        .Formatter = New XmlMessageFormatter(New Type() {GetType(structEvent)})
        '.EnableConnectionCache = True
        'purge any existing messages currently in queue
        .Purge()
        '.BeginReceive()
      End With
    Catch ex As Exception
      Call LogError(ex)
    End Try

  End Sub
  Public Sub Start_RxQueue()
    Call Load_RxQueue()
    Me.RxQueue.BeginReceive()
  End Sub

  Delegate Sub UpdateUIHandler(ByVal objQueueDataFields As structEvent)


  Sub UpdateUI(ByVal objQueueDataFields As structEvent)

    Try

      'check to see if thread switch is required
      If Me.InvokeRequired = True Then
        'switch control over to the primary UI thread
        Dim handler As New UpdateUIHandler(AddressOf UpdateUI_Impl)

        Dim args() As Object = {objQueueDataFields}


        'call begin invoke method of form object
        Me.BeginInvoke(handler, args)

      Else

        Call UpdateUI_Impl(objQueueDataFields)

      End If

    Catch ex As Exception
      Call LogError(ex)

    End Try

  End Sub
  Sub UpdateUI_Impl(ByVal qData As structEvent)

    Try

      Call DecodeUI(qData)

    Catch ex As Exception
      Call LogError(ex)
    End Try


  End Sub
  Sub DecodeUI(ByVal qDecodeData As structEvent)


    Try

      Select Case qDecodeData.inputNo
        Case 0
          'list files to screen
          Call List_Files()

        Case 1
          Call AddToList("confirm pressed")
          Call LogDataFiles()

          'list files to screen with CRC checked
          'Call List_Files()

          Call AddToList("Finished")

        Case 2
          'delete existing files
          Call Delete_Files()

        Case 100
          'initial read of existing files
          Me.lstData.Items.Clear()
          Call List_Files()


      End Select


    Catch ex As Exception
      Call LogError(ex)
    End Try

  End Sub
```

Comment: this error code mean that some pointer passed to `CreateFile` is invalid. almost 100% this is `strFileName` bad

Comment: All of those P/Invoke declarations are for Visual Basic 6. Such declarations are usually not compatible with .NET. You should try to avoid using any `Declare Function` declarations that you find and instead look for those using `DllImport`. Check https://pinvoke.net/ for the (hopefully more) correct declarations. If you cannot find a `DllImport` declaration for VB.NET then look for one in C# and convert it using http://converter.telerik.com/

Comment: I am 99% positive filenames are fine, but will recheck them nonetheless.  It does work fine when running from source.

Comment: I will try the DllImport.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Just wanted to point out: Using `DllImport` doesn't stop the declarations from being incorrect, but you have a better chance of finding correct, working P/Invokes if you **only** look for declarations of that type (as said you should be able to find most of them at https://pinvoke.net/). So even if it turns out that the problem **wasn't** caused by using old P/Invoke declarations, switching to the hopefully more correct `DllImport` declarations will save you some headache in the future.

Comment: Way too much code here. But you need to debug it. Find the error code when the API call fails. Definitely use pinvoke with SetLastError to achieve that.

Comment: I don't understand why you are using API I/O in the first place, why not use something from System.IO? Native API calls should never be your first choice (and if API calls must be used I would seriously consider writing a thin interop layer in c++ as that can still include the SDK headers and so you don't have to worry so much about the declarations being wrong).

Comment: If you don't know, what error code 998 means, open a watch window in your debugger, and enter `998,hr`. That will display both the symbolic constant as well as a human-readable error description: `ERROR_NOACCESS: Invalid access to memory location.` One of your pointers is bad. Figure out, which one. Luckily, since you followed the instructions above, you are already running under a debugger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Visual Vincent.  Per his suggestion in comment, I modified the WriteFile declaration to use the DllImport.

Code runs fine from source and executable now.  Here is the declaration I changed to for reference.

```
<DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=System.Runtime.InteropServices.CharSet.Auto)>
Public Function CreateFile(ByVal lpFileName As String,
    ByVal dwDesiredAccess As Int32,
    ByVal dwShareMode As Int32,
    ByVal lpSecurityAttributes As IntPtr,
    ByVal dwCreationDisposition As Int32,
    ByVal dwFlagsAndAttributes As Int32,
    ByVal hTemplateFile As IntPtr) As Int32
End Function
```